# Error Starting R, The R session failed to start

Tags: r, rstudio

I have seen the message after I terminated R, as one of options proposed while I was constantly getting this message **R is taking longer than usual**

I am using R x 64 Version 4.1.0

```
RStudio 1.4.1717, "Juliet Rose" (df86b69e, 2021-05-24) for Windows
```

Several times, I have attempted to uninstall(and clean AppData)/ reinstall both R and Rstudio, with no improvement.

Comment: Does the R console run correctly outside of RStudio?  This would help clarify if the problem is with your computer running R itself or with RStudio.

Comment: Yes, R console runs well outside RStudio

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough information to determine the problem here.  It may be a system or Windows problem instead of with RStudio itself.  When this happens I just reboot the system and reduce the software load.  Hope this issue is transient.

Comment: Rstudio takes around 30 minutes to open, and before it does, the following error message pops up: git.exe Application Error, the application was unable to start correctly (0xC0000142). Click ok to close the application.

Comment: That version of R is several years out of date. You might try finding a version of Rstudio the the ancient past and try to get your versions contemporaneous.

Answer (score 1):

A reinstallation of RStudio should fix this.

Comment: I have tried reinstallation and it still doesn't work. I even cleaned up my disk to free up space but nothing changes.

Comment: Personally, I am using a Mac. What happened was I tried updating the R version. After, I started getting that error. I then deleted RStudio and reinstalled it, then everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various solutions and they didn't work. But, I realised that this problem was present only if my iPhone was connected to my laptop via wire. If I launch RStudio, while the iPhone is not connected - it is all fine. If I connect it after the launch of RStudio it also works fine. Hope it hepls. (I work on Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is
type in run command

%localappdata%\RStudio

remove R studio folder from this location

install r studio it will work.